# How can I commit files currently displayed in Vim with fugitive?

Tags: git, vim, vim-fugitive

I am editing files opened split into three windows. I want to commit those into the repository. Is there any commands to do that?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish this task. I will outline the most interactive method which uses `:Git`.

- Open up the status window via `:Git`
- Move between files via `<c-n>`/`<c-p>`
- Stage/unstage files via `-`
- Start committing via `cc` whilst in the status window
- Create commit message and save and close window. (I prefer `:x`)
- You can also use `zj` and `zk` to move between sections
- Using `-` on a section will stage/unstage all the files in that section

For more help with `:Git` see `:h :Git` or `:G` when in the `:Git` buffer.

Can use `:Gwrite` or `:Gw` and `:windo` to skip the `:Git` window to make this a bit faster.

```
:windo Gw
:Git commit
```

You can also skip the whole commit window by using the `-m` flag. e.g. `:Git commit -m "A short message"`

I recommend [official repo on GitHub](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) and [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) videos on Fugitive: [The Fugitive Series - a retrospective](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2011/05/the-fugitive-series/)

To learn more see:

```
:h fugitive
:h :Git
:h :Gw
:h :Git commit
:h :windo
:h :x
```

Comment: Very helpful.  The one complaint I have is that after doing `:x` to save the commit message, the status window closes too.  But I often have both the status window open and the index and working copy diffed.  I'm adding changes piecemeal using `diffget` (the improved version of the `--patch` workflow described in the 2nd vimcast).  So what I really want is to be able to commit (and I do want to use the full window to compose my possibly multi-line message), but I don't want the status window to close after saving.  Is this possible?

Comment: You may wan to do verbose commit `cvc` in the `:Gstatus` window or `:Gcommit --verbose`. It will open a commit message in a new tab with more your commit details

Answer (score 3):

Without fugitive:

```
:windo !git add %
:!git commit -m "My message goes here"
```

The last command could be replaced with:

```
:!git commit --interactive
```